# How to get current term in my custom taxonomy in WordPress?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I need to display the current term in my custom taxonomy in a single post.

**example:**

- My custom taxonomy is *products* and term of them is *product-1*, *product-2* and *products-3*.
- My post is assigned to *product-2*
- And I want to print the current products = *products-2* in my post

In fact, I need a function like WordPress's `the_category();` but for my taxonomy like `the_customtaxonomy();`

UPDATE :

in facts i know i need to get id of this becuse i need to show a icon for this in my single , for example a function like `the_category_ID();`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`get_the_term_list()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list):

> #### Description
>
> Returns an HTML string of taxonomy terms associated with a post and given taxonomy. Terms are linked to their respective term listing pages.
>
> #### Usage
>
> ```
> <?php get_the_term_list( $id, $taxonomy, $before, $sep, $after ) ?>
> ```

Comment: the only problem with get_the_term_list is that it wraps the terms in html. use wp_get_object_terms() to get an array of terms back

Comment: In that case you could use `get_the_terms` instead.

Comment: @anu, Well, he did say he wanted a function like `the_category`, which *also* wraps the terms in HTML.

Answer (score 4):

tanks for answer from my friend , i find it for show slug of my taxonomy

```
<?php
 $terms = get_terms('my-taxonomy-name');
 foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
 echo $term->slug.' ';
 }
?>
```

and 
but it return all term in my taxonomy and i need to return current term in my taxonomy ..

**UPDATE :**

i finaly find this and add if for empty terms and works

```
<?php   // Get terms for post
 $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'oil' );
 // Loop over each item since it's an array
 if ( $terms != null ){
 foreach( $terms as $term ) {
 // Print the name method from $term which is an OBJECT
 print $term->slug ;
 // Get rid of the other data stored in the object, since it's not needed
 unset($term);
} } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found it:

```
<?php 
//list terms in a given taxonomy using wp_list_categories (also useful as a widget if using a PHP Code plugin)

$taxonomy     = 'genre';
$orderby      = 'name'; 
$show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$title        = '';

$args = array(
  'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
  'orderby'      => $orderby,
  'show_count'   => $show_count,
  'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
  'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
  'title_li'     => $title
);
?>

<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
</ul>
```

It gets all terms in my custom taxonomy and I need to get current term.

Comment: For your images, you should use CSS pseudo selectors to inject your icons.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`wp_get_object_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms)

`wp_get_object_terms( $object_ids, $taxonomies, $args )`

- $object_ids: string or array ids for the objects you want to get terms for
- $taxonomies: string or array of taxonomies

Answer (score 0):

```
echo get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'tax_name', 'Product:' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking what user3208 coded, I have added a bit of code that adds the URL to the Term. Hope that helps someone out.

```
<?php   // Get terms for post
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'oil' );
// Loop over each item since it's an array
if ( $terms != null ){
foreach( $terms as $term ) {
$term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'oil' );
 // Print the name and URL
echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
// Get rid of the other data stored in the object, since it's not needed
unset($term); } } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

*A bit of update on the subject as this question is about 11 years old, and nobody mentioned it.*

---

### You can use [`get_query_var()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/).

> Retrieves the value of a query variable in the [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) class.
> to get the current term being queried on a taxonomy page.

Instead of doing a other query, we're just fetching the term from the current one. Then we can echoed it out on the front-end.

```
<?= get_query_var( 'term' ); ?>
```