# How do I get terms as a list for a specific post?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

get_terms allows me to get all taxonomy values, but how do I limit this to a certain post?

I don't see anyway to feed a specific post ID to get_terms: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

Perhaps there is another way to achieve this?

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9414/how-to-get-current-term-in-my-custom-taxonomy-in-wordpress (ignore the question title, the answers are relevant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahah! I need to use get_the_terms instead, as this will accept a post ID.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms

Answer (score 0):

```
wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy )
```

will return an array of the term objects for that post of that taxonomy. `$post_id` can also be an array of ids (this will return all terms attached to any post in the array), and `$taxonomy` can also be an array of taxonomies.