# Display current taxonomy term when inside custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

Well, this should be pretty simple, however I couldn't find answer anywhere on the web. all answers I found were close but no exactly what I needed.
what I need is to display just the current term of a custom post type I am in.
**not all the terms just one!** (the relevant one)

this is what I'm using but it displays ALL the terms which is not good for me:

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'genre';
$queried_term = get_query_var($taxonomy);
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy, 'slug='.$queried_term);
if ($terms) {
  foreach($terms as $term) {
    echo $term->name;
  }
}
?>
```

remember - I would like to display it in my single post type template
can anyone suggest?
thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, so I finally found what I needed here:
[How to get current term in my custom taxonomy in WordPress?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9414/how-to-get-current-term-in-my-custom-taxonomy-in-wordpress)

the last update at the bottom courtesy of @user3208:

```
<?php   // Get terms for post
 $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'oil' );
 // Loop over each item since it's an array
 if ( $terms != null ){
 foreach( $terms as $term ) {
 // Print the name method from $term which is an OBJECT
 print $term->slug ;
 // Get rid of the other data stored in the object, since it's not needed
 unset($term);
} } ?>
```

That solved my issue!
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You should use [`wp_get_post_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) instead.

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy, $args );
```

[`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) will give you all the terms present in a taxonomy.

**UPDATE:**

```
global $post;
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'genre');
print_r($terms); #displays the output
```

Comment: I am trying but it's not working. do I have to pass any vars into the function? can you specify how should I implement it in my code?  Thanks

Comment: If you are in the WordPress Loop, you can use `get_the_ID()` instead of `$post_id`. For `$taxonomy`, you need to add the name of the taxonomy you're using. `$args` isn't necessary.

Comment: It's definitely outside the loop! just cant get it to work.. can you suggest how to implement it outside the loop? if necassary I will post the whole code.  Thanks

Comment: Then you need to add `global $post;` and then use `$post->ID` to get the post ID.

Comment: can you show me an example using my code above? I am not that programmer. I'll appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: updated the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work:  1. It gives me an art

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work for me: 1. it gives me an error displaying unnecessary array (probably you cant ignore the '$arg' parameter. 2. it didn't change the term name when I displayed a post from another term.  any other solution?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Taking what user3208 coded, I have added a bit of code that adds the URL to the Term. Hope that helps someone out.

```
<?php   // Get terms for post
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'oil' );
// Loop over each item since it's an array
if ( $terms != null ){
foreach( $terms as $term ) {
$term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'oil' );
 // Print the name and URL
echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
// Get rid of the other data stored in the object, since it's not needed
unset($term); } } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'yourtaxonomy', '', ', ' ); ?>
```

Comment: Code only answers are usually frowned upon without an explanation. Could you please [edit your answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/272817/edit) and explain what this function does and how this would solve the original problem, maybe linking to The Codex for more information?